# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1-e^{-n}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I attempted to prove this using the definition of convergence to a real number. I am new to proofs and would like to know whether this is valid?

Also, is there a general rule on how much information needs to be specified in proofs? Thanks

I am new to posting questions on this site so if I have posted incorrectly please let me know.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgxl3.jpg

--

Update: added Mathjax text

$
\text { Prove } \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n-1}{n} \rightarrow 1 \\
\text { To show: } \forall \varepsilon>0 . \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text { .st. } \forall n>N . \\
\left|\frac{n-1}{n}-1\right|<\varepsilon \\
\left|\frac{n-1}{n}-\frac{n}{n}\right|<\varepsilon \\
\left|-\frac{1}{n}\right|<\varepsilon \\
\frac{1}{n}<\varepsilon \\
 n>\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \\
\text {take } N=\left\lceil\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right\rceil
$

Comment: It's generally best to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting an image, because images are not searchable and can't be read by a screen reader.

Comment: +1 to your query, for nice work shown, other than the criticism in DMcMor's comment, which I agree with.  Employing $N = \max(0, \lceil -\ln 2\epsilon \rceil)$ was a nice touch, that
has a minor flaw.  Since you want $n > -\ln 2\epsilon$, your specification will 
fail if $- \ln 2\epsilon$ is a positive integer.  I am assuming that your
definition of convergence is that the inequality must apply to each element $a_n$ in the sequence where $n \geq N$.  An easy fix is to add $+1$ to
your specification for $N$.

Answer (score 1):

$n \ge 1:$

Recall: $e^n=1+n+n^2/2! +.... >n$

$f(n):=|\dfrac{1-e^{-n}}{2}-1/2|=$

$\dfrac{e^{-n}} {2}= \dfrac{1}{2e^n} <\dfrac{1}{n}.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Archimedean Principle:

There is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.

$N >1/\epsilon.$

For $n \ge N$

$f(n) <\dfrac{1}{n} \le \dfrac{1}{N} <\epsilon. $

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of a limit,

$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n = a, \text{ if }\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N\in \mathbb{N}\text{ s.t. }\forall n > N, |a_n - a| < \varepsilon.
$$

Let's take $\varepsilon > 0$.

Let's consider

$$
\left|\frac{1-e^{-n}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right| = \left|\frac{-e^{-n}}{2}\right| = \frac{e^{-n}}{2} < \varepsilon \Rightarrow n > \ln\left(\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\right),
$$

which means that $N$ can be taken as an *integer part* of $\ln\left(\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\right)$, i.e. $N = \left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\right)\right]$.

Now, we can conclude that

$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1-e^{-n}}{2}=\frac{1}{2},
$$

because $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists N = \left[\ln\left(\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\right)\right]\text{ s.t. }\forall n > N, \left|\frac{1-e^{-n}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right| < \varepsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

As $e^{-n}$ decreases to $0$, this term vanishes and the limit is obviously $\dfrac12$. Now you have to show that the deviation from the limit, $\left|\dfrac{1-e^{-n}}2-\dfrac12\right|=\dfrac{e^{-n}}2$ can be made as small as you want ($<\epsilon$) for all $n$ sufficiently large.

If you find $N$ such that $\dfrac{e^{-N}}2<\epsilon$, it is clear that $n>N\implies\dfrac{e^{-n}}2$ because the negative exponential is a decreasing function. Remains to show that $N$ can always be found, for any $\epsilon>0$.

Using logarithms, we find that $N\ge-\log(2\epsilon)$ will work, and is always possible.

---

You can also reason without logarithms. Take a number above $\dfrac1{2\epsilon}$, which has $d$ digits. Now if you divide $d$ times by $e^3>10$, the result will certainly be less than $1$. Hence $N=3d$ will do.